# Determine uniformly convergence

Tags: real-analysis

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $f_n : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ by $f_n(x) = \dfrac{nx^3}{1+n^2x^2}$.

a) Find $f$ so that $f_m \to f$ on $[0,\infty)$.

b) Is it true that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly?

I have $f'_n(x) = \dfrac{nx^2(3+n^2x^2)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}=0\implies x=0$ and then $f'_n(0) = 0$ so that $f_n \to 0$. Since I got $x=0$ instead of $x =$something with $n$ how should I choose $\epsilon$ in order to prove the uniform convergence? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), note that for any fixed $x \in [0, \infty)$, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{nx^3}{1 + n^2 x^2} = 0
$$
since the numerator is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $1$ and the denominator is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $2 > 1$. The interpretation of this statement is that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise. Hence, the pointwise limit function $0$ is our only candidate for the uniform limit, as uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.

For part (b), let's see if $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, which happens by definition iff for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
n \geq N \implies \sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} \left| f_n(x) - 0 \right| < \epsilon. \tag{1}
$$
Now your derivative computations come in handy to compute $\sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} f_n(x)$ (we omit absolute values since it's clear that $f_n \geq 0$). We try to solve
$$
0 = f'_n(x) = \frac{n x^2 \left(n^2 x^2+3\right)}{\left(n^2 x^2+1\right)^2} 
$$
for $x$; the only real solution is $x = 0$, so either the supremum occurs at $x = 0$ or it occurs as $x \to \infty$. By looking at the graph of $f_n$, it's clear that $f_n(x) \to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, which we can also compute: for each fixed $n$, 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{nx^3}{1 + n^2 x^2} = \infty
$$
since the numerator is a degree $3$ polynomial in $x$ and the denominator is a degree $2 < 3$ polynomial in $x$.

Since $\sup_{x \in [0, \infty)} f_n(x) = \infty$, the definition $(1)$ of uniform continuity cannot be satisfied, so $f_n$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n.$ For fixed $x> 0,$ the expression is less than $(nx^3)/(n^2x) = x^2/n \to 0.$ Thus $f_n \to 0$ pointwise on $[0,\infty).$ (Not sure why you took derivatives here.)

If the convergence to $0$ were uniform, then we would have

$$\sup_{[0,\infty)} |f_n| \to 0.$$

Since $f_n(n) = n^4/(1+n^4) \to 1,$ this fails.